# python idleの実行を別のウィンドウでしたい

Tags: python, python-idle

タイトルの通りです。
pythonのidleではF5キーで実行するとどのプログラムの処理結果も１つのウィンドウ内に表示されます。
しかし、２つのプログラムを交互に実行したいときには何度も実行し直さなくてはならず不便です。
同時に複数のウィンドウに処理結果を表示しておくことはできないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDLEを必要な分だけ複数立ち上げて、それぞれ１つづつプログラムを担当させておけば良いのではないでしょうか？

Comment: いくつも立ち上げられるのですね。ありがとうございます。